# send data from activity to another without start it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

If I have two activities Activity1 and Activity2 and I want to send data from Activity1  to Activity2 without Start Activity2

I know if I want to start Activity2 I use this code in Activity1.java

```
Intent intent ;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString(BG_SELECT, hexColor);

intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);

intent.putExtras(bundle);

// this is to start but I want just refresh Activity2 not start it
startActivityForResult(intent, uniqueNo);
```

and in Activity2.java

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle != null) {
   bgColor = bundle.getString(SebhaActivity.BG_SELECT);
   System.out.println("in Activity2, selected BG: "+bgColor);

}
```

How to refresh Activity2 to find data in it without Start it?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think the downvotes for this question are uncalled for. Even if the Activities are misunderstood by the O.P. the question is still asked by many Android beginners, and a good answer would guide them along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the next activity (where you need data, Activity2 i.e) wont start from here you can save the data in SharedPreferences in Activity 1 and access it in  activity2 when you get there

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). For your scenario, i.e., Activity1 sends something to Activity2, you would do something like the following.

```
# Activity1

Intent intent = new Intent("INTENT_NAME").putExtra(BG_SELECT, hexColor);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Activity1.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

On Activity2, you would need first to register the receiver, for instance, on its onCreate method, then get the intent using a BroadcastReceiver as following

```
# Activity2

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("INTENT_NAME"));
}
```

Then, register the `mReceiver` to retrieve the `BG_SELECT` field

```
# Activity2

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String receivedHexColor = intent.getStringExtra(BG_SELECT);
    }
};
```

Comment: When it calls in activity 2 screen blinks for a second , What may be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Create one non activity class.

```
  public class Datas {
  public static String name;
  }
```

Declare this non activity class in your activity class.

```
Data  mData = new Data();
String str = mData.name
```

Comment: But this not secure enough

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share data between 2 activities while both are running, you should using some storage available for both.

Check the `Shared Preferences`, or make a global storage class that can be accessed in both activities. There is no real "method" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think here SharedPreferences is become unbeatable.

> SharedPreferences is application specific, i.e. the data is lost on
> performing one of the following options: PREFS_NAME is the name of the
> file. mode is the operating mode. editor.commit() is used in order to
> save changes to shared preferences

**Your Code goes like this**

In First Activity From where you share data

```
  SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("PhoneBook",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("registration_id",c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("db_regiser_id")));
    editor.putBoolean("IsLogin",true);
    editor.commit();
```

In Second Activity get data like this

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("PhoneBook",MODE_PRIVATE);
 int registration_id = preferences.getInt("registration_id", 0);
```

> Use of SharedPreferences is quite safe.

**Also visit**

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Hope this one will be helpful.