# Call an Android main activity function that is running in a foreground service from a broadcast receiver that was received from an Action Button?

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I am having a very hard time to communicate from a broadcast receiver to a foreground service main activity.  All I want to do is take what I got from the broadcast receiver and call A function that is running in a foreground service.  I am trying not to use a static method because I need to call a method that can not be static.  And If I try and make an instance of the class I get an error because the class might not be running. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` Is there another way to do this?  Maybe I'm thinking about this in the complete wrong way.  I have a Main Class, Service Class, and a broadcast receiver class.  Anything would help. Thank you!

**AppService.java**

```
    public class AppService extends Service
{

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId)
{
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

     Intent ActionCancelIntent = new Intent(this,ActionCancelReceiver.class);

     PendingIntent CancelIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,ActionCancelIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(TopText)
                .setContentText(BottomText)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map_marker,CancelName,CancelIntent);

        startForeground(1,notificationBuilder.build());

     return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
}
```

**ActionCancelReceiver.java**

```
public class ActionCancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    public String TAG = "MyApp";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Clicked Cancel");

        CancelActionButton();

        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(it);
    }

}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    public static final String TAG = "MyApp";

 public static void CancelActionButton()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"CancelActionMain");
}
```

This code works and prints out CancelActionMain but I want to put a nonstatic method in CancelActionButton().  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post relevant code?

Comment: @Acroyear I added some code.  Please let me know If more would help.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833840/send-data-from-activity-to-another-without-start-it) for how to send an `Intent` to an `Activity` without forcing it to exist. Check out the most upvoted answer. Your foreground service doesn't really play a role in this solution.