# Trying to pass EditText value to two different activities with one button in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to pass EditText values to two different activities with "**submit**" button. So far i've managed to pass on to one of the activities. But when I enter second activity values aren't passed. There's nothing passed. Below there will be four activities: "**TwoTeam**"(activity where user enters data in textedit.), "**Begin**"(first activity where I want to pass values.), "**BeginAfter**"(activity where is one minute timer and after timer reaches 0 it will navigate user to next activity), "**Begindup**"(second activity where i want to pass those text values. Activity where is the problem. It doesn't shows values.). Here is activity "**TwoTeam**":

```
public class TwoTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first_name, second_name;
    String name_first;
    String name_second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_team);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.second_name);

    }

    public void submit_button(View view) {
        name_first = first_name.getText().toString();
        name_second = second_name.getText().toString();
        Intent in = new Intent(TwoTeam.this, Begindup.class);{
            in.putExtra("name1", name_first);
            in.putExtra("name2", name_second);
            in.putExtra("turn2", name_second + "'s Turn");
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(TwoTeam.this, Begin.class);{
            intent.putExtra("name1", name_first);
            intent.putExtra("name2", name_second);
            intent.putExtra("turn1", name_first + "'s Turn");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's activity "**Begin**":

```
public class Begin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView first_name, second_name, turn, words;
    String name_first, name_second, turns;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.name_first);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.name_second);
        turn = findViewById(R.id.turn1);

        name_first = getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
        first_name.setText(name_first);

        name_second = getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
        second_name.setText(name_second);

        turns = getIntent().getStringExtra("turn1");
        turn.setText(turns);
    }

    public void start_button(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeginAfter.class);{
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's activity "**BeginAfter**":

```
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%01d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));
                textView.setText(sDuration);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                startActivity(new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begindup.class));
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Aaand here's activity "**Begindup**":

```
public class Begindup extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView first_name, second_name, turn, words;
    String name_first, name_second, turns;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begindup);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.name_first);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.name_second);
        turn = findViewById(R.id.turn2);

        name_first = getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
        first_name.setText(name_first);

        name_second = getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
        second_name.setText(name_second);

        turns = getIntent().getStringExtra("turn2");
        turn.setText(turns);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it answers a question similar to yours - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833840/send-data-from-activity-to-another-without-start-it/33519655

Comment: Can you please write down some code cause i tried shared preferences befor and it didn't work

Comment: No need to put code! I already did it. Your comment helped me! Thakns!!!

Comment: No problem at all